# Measure theory limits question convention

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the following lemma:

If $(X,S,\mu)$ is a measure space and $(E_n)_n$  is an increasing sequences of sets of the sigma algebra $S$, then $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i)=\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}\mu(E_i)$.

My questions are:

(1) How is the limit above defined? $\mu(E_i)\in [0,\infty]$, and i'm not sure if we can manipulate the standard metric in a natural manner to define limits on $[0,\infty]$.

(2) Is it a convention to assume that if $(x_n)_n$ is a non-negative increasing sequence such that $x_n=\infty$ for some $n$, then $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that since the sequence of sets in increasing, if any one of them has $\mu(E_i)=\infty$, then $\mu(E_j)=\infty$ for all $j\geq i$ (monotonicity of measures). Therefore (1) either it is a limit of true real numbers, or it is a limit of a sequence where all the terms are eventually infinity (ie. $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,\infty,\infty,\infty,...)$. In the former case you know how to handle it; in the latter the limit is taken to be infinity. (2) That convention would not make sense if only a single term $x_n=\infty$, but it does in this case for the reason above.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of limit applies exactly as in the limits of $\mathbb{R}$. Namely, one says that $x_n\rightarrow L\in[0,\infty)$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^{>N}$ we have $|L-x_n|<\infty$. In here, $|L-\infty|:=\infty$. On the other hand, $x_n\rightarrow\infty$ if for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$ there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^{>N}$ we have $x_n>M$. In particular, every increasing sequence that eventually equals $\infty$ converges to $\infty$.